# Convert GPS coordinate to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I´m building a PHP system where the user will type some GPS coordinates into a table and then the web system will pinpoint that position using google maps. In future we will develop an app for that, but for now the user has to type on the web page his coordinates.

My problem is regarding converting the cellular GPS coordinates to google maps format. We are using the cellular coordinates as  decimal degrees `DD.DDDD` and the cellular show these values ie:

```
20.23223oS, 46.2737oO
```

But google maps accepts real numbers, as:

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(20.23223, 46.2737)
```

With this code it does not show the location I can see on my cellular.

How can I convert the above coordinates to google maps ? Can someone has a PHP code for example ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The location is in Madagascar?

Comment: Or the location is  In Brazil ?

Comment: No, South America - Brazil, but shows as Middle Orient in google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ith the location is in Brazil youn simply should remove the last two char for lat (oS) S= South and for lng (oO) O = West  and change the sign (both are negative)

Make sure your conversion obtain an negative  latitude,  longitute (West) in some case if you don't speficy correctly google maps could convert automatically postive value

Comment: No. For me it shows Saudi Arabia if I only take off the letters. Check http://jsfiddle.net/805bd2Lh/

Comment: I have update the answer .. if  don't specified google maps get positive value this make me wrong

Comment: Brazil 200 KM west Belo Horizont

Comment: So, the rule is: South must convert to negative, West must convert to negative ?

Comment: Exactly for Google Maps North = postive Latitude , East = positive Longitude. then South = negative Latitude and West = negative Longitude..